# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize lombok's Fields

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

IntelliJ recognize lombok annotations including @FieldNameConstants and I can import the generated fields via: 
 `import static com.somepackage.SomeClass.Fields.field` (even autocomplete works after typing 'SomeClass' or 'Fields'). 
However when I want to build the project it says :

```
 java: cannot find symbol
 symbol: class Fields
 location: com.somepackage.SomeClass
```

Intelli version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-193.5233.102, built on November 28, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b520.11 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 2000M
Cores: 4
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: Lombook Plugin
```

Lombok version:

```
1.18.8 (tried it also with 1.18.10)
```

The same project(maven based springboot) works well in eclipse.
Lombok is correctly installed and annotation preprocesing is enabled. I have tried several uninstalls (both the ide and lombok) and clean project imports. Same result.

Comment: Do you have "Lombok" plugin installed as well?

Comment: of course as I stated above.

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?